# Hello, my menu button for xs screen range is always present and does not function correclty, I am pretty certain the issue is with my JS files

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

ill attach my entire code below, when run in the browser the menu button shows the `sr-only` text, additionally the clickable drop down menu button shows regardless of pixel range. could it be a problem with my bootstrap JS file?:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en zxx">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Module3 solution</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href = "css/stISLE.css" >
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src = "js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/mod3script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>



      <nav id ="header-nav" class = "navbar navbar-default">
        <div class ="container-fluid">
          <div class = "navbar-brand" id ="myBrand">PotatoSalad, PJSC</div>

        <div class = "navbar-header">
          <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle collapsed"
          data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#collapsable-nav2" aria-expanded = "false">
          <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
          </button>


      <div id = "collapsable-nav2" class = "collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav visible-xs">



          <li><a href = "#"> yes </a></li>
          <li><a href = "#"> no  </a></li>
          <li><a href = "#"> maybe so</a></li>


        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      </nav> 
    </header>
  </body>
  </html>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en zxx">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Module3 solution</title>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" href = "css/stISLE.css" >
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src = "js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/mod3script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>



      <nav id ="header-nav" class = "navbar navbar-default">
        <div class ="container-fluid">
          <div class = "navbar-brand" id ="myBrand">PotatoSalad, PJSC</div>

        <div class = "navbar-header">
          <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggle collapsed"
          data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#collapsable-nav2" aria-expanded = "false">
          <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
          <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

      <div id = "collapsable-nav2" class = "collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav visible-xs">

          <li><a href = "#"> yes </a></li>
          <li><a href = "#"> no  </a></li>
          <li><a href = "#"> maybe so</a></li>


        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav> 
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Greetings, I have learned that my issue was with linking the bootstrap files. I have figured it out. What I used in the head tag were the following script tags:                                       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>              Thank you :).